# How to efficiently find the maximum value out of this function?

Tags: functions

I apologize in advance. I am not a mathematician, so I do not know the proper terminology and notation. I am a software developer, and my software uses a function that I believe is very inefficient.

**I need to find the value of x that results in the maximum value out of the function.**

Currently, I will iterate over different x values thousands of times and compare the results of the function until I find the highest value. I suspect that there is a more efficient way to achieve this, perhaps like a formula that would give me the answer in one calculation instead of thousands iterations.

**I also have a major constraint: I can only use integers.** If an operation results in a decimal number (like a division), all the decimals will be truncated. I do not need an exact result for this calculation, but it should be reasonably precise.

In the function below, $c_{1}$ and $b_{1}$ to $b_{6}$ are given. I need to be able to change them in the formula between cycles, but I already know their value when I start iterating over different values of x. For instance, I would know that for a given cycle $c_{1} = 999$, $b_{1} = 123401014$, $b_{2} = 231248124$, etc.

Here is the function for which I need to find the value of x corresponding to $max(f(x))$:
$$
f(x) = x \times \frac{c_{1} \times b_{1}}{b_{2} \times 10000 + (x \times c_{1})} \times \frac{c_{1} \times b_{3}}{b_{4} \times 10000 + (\frac{x \times c_{1} \times b_{1}}{b_{2} \times 10000 + (x \times c_{1})} \times c_{1})} \times \frac{c_{1} \times b_{5}}{b_{6} \times 10000 + (\frac{c_{1} \times b_{3}}{b_{4} \times 10000 + (\frac{x \times c_{1} \times b_{1}}{b_{2} \times 10000 + (x \times c_{1})} \times c_{1})} \times c_{1})}
$$
Thank you so much in advance!

**EDIT: x must be a positive integer. All the constants $c_{1}$ and $b_{1}$ to $b_{6}$ are also positive integers.**

Comment: Are the constants $c_1,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5,b_6$ always positive integers?

Comment: Yes, I will edit to specify this too.

Comment: First step:  simplify the expression so that it is a ratio of two polynomials in x.  Then using elementary calculus find x for the maximum.  The integer you want will be the nearest integer to x.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Believe it or not, but what you are describing is beyond my comprehension. I haven't done any math since high school which was... a long time ago! I guess that I could re-learn it but I will most likely not have time until forever.

Comment: I'll try to lead the way.  Your second expression (looking only as a function of x) looks like $\frac{A}{B+\frac{Cx}{D+Ex}}=\frac{A(D+Ex)}{B(D+Ex)+Cx}=\frac{AD+AEx}{BD+(BE+C)x}$.  The third expression will require two steps rather than one.

Comment: @herb I don't think it's always the case that the integer maximizing a function $f(x)$ is the integer nearest the real maximizing $f(x)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In theory you are correct, but in a practical problem there would a little work to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to simplify the formula.  The way I see it,
$$f(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)f_3(3)$$
where $$\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=\frac{b_1c_1x}{10000b_2+c_1x}\\
f_2(x)&=\frac{c_1b_3}{10000b_4+c_1f_1(x)}\\
f_3(x)&=\frac{c_1b_5}{10000b_6+c_1f_2(x)}
\end{align}$$
Please check carefully that I haven't made a mistake.

$f_1$ has the form of a linear polynomial divided by a linear polynomial, say $$f_1(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$ so $f_2(x)$ has the form $$f_2(x)=\frac{A}{B+C\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}}=\frac{Acx+Ad}{(Bc+Ca)x+(Bd+Cb)}$$ which is again a linear polynomial divided by a linear polynomial.  The same logic shows that when we substitute $f_2$ into $f_3$, we will again get a linear polynomial divided by a linear polynomial.

Since $f$ is the product of three functions of this form,. $f$ is a cubic divided by a cubic, and the formula for the derivative of a quotient shows that that the numerator of the derivative will be a fourth-degree polynomial.  The roots of this polynomial, will be the critical points of $f(x)$.  The values of $x$ at which local maxima and minima occur.

you can get the formula for the numerator of the derivative once and for all, as an expression involving $c_1,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5,b_6$ with a computer algebra system.  Then you can plug in the actual values of these constants and get quartic polynomial that you'll need to solve numerically.  The CAS should be able to do that for you too.  There are four roots.  Of course, the roots will probably not be positive integers, and they may not all be real.  You need to take the positive roots, and check the the values of $f$ at the two integers closest to the roots.  You should also check at $x=1$.  At worst, you have to check $9$ values.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I wrote this little python script

```
from sympy import ratsimp, symbols, latex

x,c1,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6=symbols('x,c1,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6')
TTHOU=10000
f1  = b1*c1*x/(TTHOU*b2+c1*x)
f2 = c1*b3/(TTHOU*b4+c1*f1)
f3= c1*b5/(TTHOU*b6+c1*f2)
f=ratsimp(f1*f2*f3)
lat = latex(f)
print(lat)
```

to calculate $f(x)$.  It produces Latex for the formula, which turns out to be $$\frac{b_{1} b_{3} b_{5} c_{1}^{3} x}{10000 b_{1} b_{6} c_{1}^{2} x + 10000 b_{2} b_{3} c_{1}^{2} + 1000000000000 b_{2} b_{4} b_{6} + b_{3} c_{1}^{3} x + 100000000 b_{4} b_{6} c_{1} x}$$

Unfortunately, it doesn't collect the terms in the denominator, but you can see that the formula is of the form $$\frac{Ax}{Bx+C}$$ where $A,B,C$ are positive integers.  When we clear denominators in the fractions, the numerator of $f_2$ turns out to be the denominator of $f1$ and the numerator of $f_3$ to be the denominator of $f_2$, so we get cancellation, and the degrees don't increase.

Now $$f(x)=\frac{Ax}{Bx+C}=\frac{A}{B+\frac Cx}$$  Since $C>0)$ we can see that as $x$ increases through positive inters, the denominator will decrease.  But if you divide by something smaller, you get something bigger, so $f(x)$ increases as $x$ does.  That means that there is no maximum value, which I find hard to reconcile with your description of your experience with this problem.

However, you may have simply been taking larger values of $x$ until you didn't see any more increase.  It's easy to figure out what the limiting value is.

$$f_1(x)=\frac{b_1c_1x}{10000b_2+c_1x}=\frac{b_1c_1}{\frac{10000b_2}x+c_1}$$  If we make $x$ large, we can make $\frac{10000b_2}x$ as close to $0$ as we care to, so the fraction gets arbitrarily close to $$\frac{b_1c_1}{c_1}=b_1$$ We substitue this limit into $f_2$ and then into $f_3$.  Time for some more sympy:

```
g1 = b1
g2 = c1*b3/(TTHOU*b4+c1*g1)
g3= c1*b5/(TTHOU*b6+c1*g2)
g=ratsimp(g1*g2*g3)
lat = latex(g)
print(lat)
```

This time we get $$\frac{b_{1} b_{3} b_{5} c_{1}^{2}}{10000 b_{1} b_{6} c_{1} + b_{3} c_{1}^{2} + 100000000 b_{4} b_{6}}\tag1$$  The function has a horizontal asymptote, which means that as $x$ gets very large, the graph looks like a horizontal line.  It actually always increases, but very, very slowly.  We never get to the value in $(1)$, but we can get as close as we like by taking $x$ large enough.

Comment: The max value on the integers may not come at an integer near the max value on the reals.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see that I neglected the poles, but are you talking about the kind of phenomenon one sees in ILP?  I'm having trouble visualizing that for a rational function of one real variable.  Do you have an example handy, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Actually, since all the constants are positive integers, there are no poles at $x\geq0$.  The critical points divide the positive $x$-axis into finitely many intervals on which $f$ is monotonic.  It's also easy to see that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists.  I think that what I said is true.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you so much! I read your answer a couple of times and had to google a few words, but now I think that I understand it. It will take me some time to implement it in my code, but I will let you know if it works. I will accept it as the official answer when it's tested. Thanks again!

Comment: @Undead8 My pleasure.

Comment: Sorry, saul, I didn't read your post carefully enough.

Comment: @saulspatz Once I have the quartic polynomial function, I can find the roots easily within my code. However, I am having trouble getting from my original equation to the "expression involving c1, b1..", which I understand should be the quartic polynomial in question (I never used a CAS and got confused by Maxima). Is using a CAS to find this function a matter of 2 minutes so that you could give it to me? Or should I take the time to learn how to use a CAS since it's more complicated than that?

Comment: @Undead8 By coincidence, I started playing around with this myself after dinner.  I get substantial cancellation, and end up with a linear polynomial divided by a linear polynomial, which, if correct, means there really is no maximum, though the function approaches an easily-computed limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$.  This doesn't seem to square with your description of the problem though.  Hang loose, I'll let you know what I came up with.  Don't worry about the CAS, I'm doing that part.

Comment: @Undead8 I've gone over this carefully, and I can't find any mistakes.  Can you check that the value computed is in reasonable agreement with the maximum you found in one of your projects?

Comment: After carefully reviewing the answer and making tests with real-world numerical values in Excel, I think that it is most likely right. However, it does not match what I experience in my code, since there really should be a max. I found out that my original function in the question had 2 mistakes based on a bad understanding of what my code was really doing. I will post another question with the correct function. Your answer really helped me to have powerful insight into what my code was actually doing.

Comment: @saulspatz Here is the correct function if by any chance you are still interested! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084594/how-to-efficiently-find-the-max-of-this-function-2