# How to efficiently find the max of this function?

Tags: functions, maxima-minima, stationary-point

I am a software developer and my software uses a function that I believe is very inefficient.

I need to find the value of x that results in the maximum value out of the function. Currently, I will iterate over different x values thousands of times and compare the results of the function until I find the highest value, which is quite inefficient.

I also have a constraint: I can only use integers. If an operation results in a decimal number (like a division), all the decimals will be truncated. I do not need an exact result for this calculation, but it should be reasonably precise.

In the function below, c1 and b1 to b6 are given constants. I need to be able to change them in the formula between cycles, but I already know their value before I need to find the max. For instance, I would know that for a given cycle $c_{1}=999$, $b_{1}=123401014$, $b_{2}=231248124$, etc.

All the constants and x are always positive integers greater than 0.

Here is the function f(x) for which I need to find the value of x corresponding to max(f(x)):

$$f(x)=x\times f_1(x)f_2(x)f_3(x)-x$$

where:
\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=\frac{b_1c_1}{10000b_2+c_1x}\\
f_2(x)&=\frac{b_3c_1}{10000b_4+c_1xf_1(x)}\\
f_3(x)&=\frac{b_5c_1}{10000b_6+c_1xf_1(x)f_2(x)}
\end{align}

I posted an almost identical question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081127/how-to-efficiently-find-the-maximum-value-out-of-this-function) and got an excellent answer, but I found out after many tests that my original function had mistakes in it.

Thanks in advance!

Here is a [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/swvdcqtw7e) of the function with typical constants values.

### Edit: Bonus question

My software also uses this slightly modified function (note the addition of $c_2$ constant):

$$f(x)=x\times f_1(x)f_2(x)-x$$

where:
\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=\frac{b_1c_1}{10000b_2+c_1x}\\
f_2(x)&=\frac{b_3c_2}{10000b_4+c_2xf_1(x)}
\end{align}

What would be this function simplified? And what would be the formula to find the stationary points?

Here is a [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8mqwf21ur1).

Comment: Doing essentially the same computational work as in the answer to your other question seems like a good way to go here too. Broadly, I would use a CAS to compute the critical points, test integers on either side of all of them, and then try to see what happens as $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$. Some of the sympy code that was written for you would work here too.

Comment: In the other question, I had to find the formula for the numerator of the derivative by using a CAS, which would give me a quartic polynomial. Then, I would need to find the roots of that polynomial and check the highest. Is that the same for that function?

Comment: I'll have to take a look at it more closely to see what the degree is.  Probably won't get to it till this evening at the earliest.

Comment: It is unclear where exactly the truncations take place. Could you provide a representative plot of the function ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The truncation of decimals is probably not relevant. I just wanted to mention it in case the solution depended heavily on using decimals. I also edited to add a plot of the function with typical constant values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

After a lot of algebra we get

$$
f(x) = \left(\frac{\alpha_1 +\alpha_2 x}{\alpha_3+\alpha_4 x}\right)x
$$

now by calculating the stationary points with $f'(x)$ we are done.

NOTE

With $a = 10^4$
$$
\cases{
\alpha_1 = b_1 b_3 b_5 c_1^3-a^3b_2 b_4 b_6\\
\alpha_2 = -(a^2b_4b_6c_1+a b_1 b_6 c_1^2+b_1b_3c_1^3)\\
\alpha_3 = a^3b_2b_4b_6\\
\alpha_4 = c_1(a^2b_4b_6+ab_1b_6c_1+b_1b_3c_1^2)
}
$$

now from $f'(x)=0$ the stationary points are located at

$$
x^* = \frac{-\alpha_2\alpha_3\pm\sqrt{\alpha_2\alpha_3(\alpha_2\alpha_3-\alpha_1\alpha_4)}}{\alpha_2\alpha_4}
$$

for the second function we have after simplifications

$$
f(x) = \left(\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_2 +\alpha_3 x}-1\right)x
$$

with

$$
\cases{
\alpha_1 = b_1b_3c_1c_2\\
\alpha_2 = a^2b_2b_4\\
\alpha_3 = c_1(a b_4+b_1c_2)
}
$$

and the stationary points are defined at $f'(x^*) = 0$ as

$$
x^* = -\frac{\alpha_2\pm\sqrt{\alpha_1\alpha_2}}{\alpha_3}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it! It seems to work perfectly when I test it with a calculator. I will implement it in my code.

Comment: I implemented your solution in my code and it worked admirably well. I use both your simplified f(x) function and the formula to find the stationary points. I edited the question to add another function that I use in that same software (it's the last one I promise!). If you feel like it, it would help me very much if you could solve it the same way as you did for the first one.

Comment: The bonus answer was included. Regards.